# SQL Join maybe?

Tags: sql, join

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = '{$_GET['id']}'");
$news = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

$sql84 = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = '".$news['user_id']."'") or exit(mysql_error());
$author = mysql_fetch_array($sql84);

is there i better way of doing this? a join maybe? how that look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want something like this:

(Edited to add error checking)

```
$q = "select username from news, users where news.user_id=users.id and news.id=".$_GET['id'].");";
$query = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
```

Ben

Comment: Looks good but it looks like you forgot an "s" on user.id should be users.id.

Comment: Oops! Well spotted. Thanks! Have fixed it now.

Comment: i get this :/

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in c/krukow/news.php on line 5

$query = mysql_query("SELECT username from news, users WHERE news.user_id = user.id and news.id = ".$_GET['newsID'].");");
$news = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

Comment: Hmmm... Not sure why. I've added error checking into the example above. You might also want to check that $_GET['id]' really contains what you expect it to contain, and perhaps try it with a hard-coded value for news.id.

Comment: this outputs
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news, users WHERE news.user_id = users.id AND news.id = ".$_GET['newsID']."");
$news = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

everything but the row "text" with is the news...it is text in it so i dont understand

Comment: Do you mean that the code gets displayed as the output of your programme? Are you running it from the command-line or in a browser? You do have <?php and ?> tags, right? It sounds like you changed something other than just the contents of the query, if it was not doing this before...

Comment: man this is what i got

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news, users WHERE news.user_id = users.id AND news.id = ".$_GET['newsID']."");
$news = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
?>
it write everything out exept text
echo $news["user_id"]; echo $news["username"];
but not
echo $news['text'];

Comment: ops i had a coluimn called text in users too...i thought i had changed that..jaja it works now thx ben

Comment: Cool! :-) (btw: if you want to accept this answer, click on the "tick" symbol under the number of votes...)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT n.*, u.* FROM news n LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id=n.user_id WHERE n.id = ".intval($_GET['id']));
```

Please don't forget to use intval() if value assumed is numeric.